# How to add a line break after a text node after an input element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen different answers on Stack Overflow, but none seem to work!

Here is the code:

```js
var input1 = document.createElement("input");
var input2 = document.createElement("input");
var input3 = document.createElement("input");
input1.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
input2.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
input3.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
var br = document.createElement("br");
var text1 = document.createTextNode("option1");
var text2 = document.createTextNode("option2");
var text3 = document.createTextNode("option3");
var se = document.getElementById("container");
input1.appendChild(text1);
input2.appendChild(text2);
input3.appendChild(text3);
se.appendChild(input1);
se.appendChild(br);
se.appendChild(input2);
se.appendChild(input3);
```

```html
<body>
    <form>
      <div id="container">
      </div>
      <br />
    </form>
</body>
```

What I'm trying to obtain is the checkbox corresponding to each input element to display vertically on top of each other with their text to the right and a line break right at the end of each line. I want to avoid using display: block for input elements in CSS.

Comment: you are appending a text node to a checkbox which will do nothing

Comment: You can not append text nodes to input elements, input elements have an empty content model. Do this properly - create a label element to hold the text, put the input into the label as well - and then use CSS to achieve the formatting you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

```js
var input1 = document.createElement("input");
var input2 = document.createElement("input");
var input3 = document.createElement("input");
input1.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
input2.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
input3.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
var br1 = document.createElement("br");
var br2 = document.createElement("br");
var br3 = document.createElement("br");
var text1 = document.createTextNode("option1");
var text2 = document.createTextNode("option2");
var text3 = document.createTextNode("option3");
var se = document.getElementById("container");

se.appendChild(input1);
se.appendChild(text1);
se.appendChild(br1);
se.appendChild(input2);
se.appendChild(text2);
se.appendChild(br2);
se.appendChild(input3);
se.appendChild(text3);
se.appendChild(br3);
```

```html
<body>
    <form>
      <div id="container">
      </div>
      <br />
    </form>
</body>
```